# Having trouble scraping an ASP .NET web page

Tags: asp.net, python

I am trying to scrape an ASP.NET website but am having trouble getting the results from a post. I have the following python code and am using httplib2 and BeautifulSoup:

```
conn = Http()
# do a get first to retrieve important values
page = conn.request(u"http://somepage.com/Search.aspx", "GET")

#event_validation and viewstate variables retrieved from GET here...

body = {"__EVENTARGUMENT" : "",
        "__EVENTTARGET" : "" ,
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": event_validation,
        "__VIEWSTATE" : viewstate,
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GovernmentCheckBox" : "On",
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_NonGovernmentCheckBox" : "On",
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SchoolKeyValue" : "",
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SchoolNameTextBox" : "",
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ScriptManager1" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel1|cct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_SearchImageButton",
        "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_SearchImageButton.x" : "375",
        "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_SearchImageButton.y" : "11",
        "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SuburbTownTextBox" : "Adelaide,SA,5000",
        "hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts" : 1}

headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
resp, content = conn.request(url,"POST", headers=headers, body=urlencode(body))
```

When I print `content` I still seem to be getting the same results as the "GET" or is there a fundamental concept I'm missing to retrieve the result values of an ASP .NET post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't technically an answer, but you could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to examine the difference between what you are sending with your python code, versus what would be sent if you used a web browser to do the post.

I find that usually helps in these types of situations.

Comment: I didn't think this would help me solve it. But it did - the code input was right. Except the urlencode function was not working properly and the `content` was just returning the response to a GET. Once the body was properly formed it returned a html page with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You need to see first what you have written in the page for get and post, but I hope you are making sure both requests are sending different contents.

here is how you can do that

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
Response.Write("<h1>Get Request</h1>");
}
else
{
Response.Write("<h1>POST Request</h1>");
}
```

I hope you are using C# as code behind